# Cleaning a Tenor Recorder lever

Tags: maintenance, recorder

I have a plastic Tenor Recorder which I understand can be washed with soapy water.

I am concerned if the lever can also be immersed or do I have to clean it another way.

Answer (score 3):

Although most of the plastic recorder can be cleaned with water and mild detergent, *since the keys have pads, you want to keep the keys dry*. From Yamaha's website:

> Resin recorders can be washed in one piece using a neutral kitchen detergent. For instruments equipped with keys, take care to avoid allowing the keys to become wet.

My Yamaha tenor recorder is built in 3 parts; I can wash the head and middle joints easily, but I need to be careful with the foot joint, since that's the section with the keys.